# Typescript Firebase Cloud Store. Typo Issue

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, visual-studio-code, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to get data from Firebase Cloud Store following de sample of angularfire2 library:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreDocument } from 'angularfire2/firestore';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
    <div>
      {{ (item | async)?.name }}
    </div>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {
  private itemDoc: AngularFirestoreDocument<Item>;
  item: Observable<Item>;
  constructor(private afs: AngularFirestore) {
    this.itemDoc = afs.doc<Item>('items/1');
    this.item = this.itemDoc.valueChanges();
  }
  update(item: Item) {
    this.itemDoc.update(item);
  }
}
```

But Typescript remarks with error the `<Item>` and says the name 'Item' has not found.

What would be the solution for this issue?

Comment: Do you need to import Item from somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[You haven't defined an `Item` interface](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html), just drop `<Item>` and the example should operate normally or you can define it:

```
interface Item {
   something: string;
   somethingElse: string;
}
```